# In Unity Player Is Spinning Instead Of Moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a 3d platformer game in Unity, so I watched one of Brackeys tutorials. After Coding in the part to Move the player with the WASD and Arrow Keys, I tested it out. But when I tried to move, instead the player would spin in place. Here's the code I used:

```c#
public CharacterController controller;
public float speed = 12f;

void Update() {
    float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

    controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I have absolutely no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`transform` is not really correct way to handle movement. Search for a special movement method for example `translate` but depends on the target and environment. I make movement in 3d space using `rigidbody` and recommend doing the same because it is the most physically accurate. Also search for tutorials on youtube, this topic was covered a lot of times there.